# How to use escape characters in metro.config module names?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

I can't seem to add resolve deep modules (i.e., module names containing "/") with `metro.config` inside a React Native project, while all modules with simple names work. Do you know how I can bypass this?

Moreover, using `resolveRequest()` isn't called so I can debug from there.

```
resolver: {
  extraNodeModules: {
    'foo': path.resolve(__dirname, '../my/path'), // works
    'fs/promises': path.resolve(__dirname, '../my/path'), // doesn't work
  },
},
```

Comment: Not sure but have you tried escaping the slashes? `fs\/promises`

Comment: @Abe Yep, it doesn't work.